# Build Date object from string and timezone

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, timezone-offset

I'm looking for a way to build a correct `Date` object given a date/time string and a timezone.

Currently I have a list of timezones with the specific offset and want to merge them simply together like this:

```
new Date(`${date} ${time} GMT${offset}`);
// new Date('2019-08-30 10:00:00 GMT+0100`);
```

But doing it like this doesn't care about dst and I get an date, which is in the summer one hour ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the offset, you can build a string in the [JavaScript date time format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format) and use that with `new Date`. The format looks like this: `2019-08-30T10:00:00+0100`.

It looks like your `offset` is the string `"+0100"`. If so:

```
new Date(`${date}T${time}${offset}`);
```

Live Example:

```js
const date = "2019-08-30";
const time = "10:00:00";
const offset = "+0100";

const dt = new Date(`${date}T${time}${offset}`);
console.log("toISOString:", dt.toISOString());
console.log("toLocaleString", dt.toLocaleString());
```

In my timezone (British Summer Time, GMT+0100) with Chrome (V8), that outputs:

```
toISOString: 2019-08-30T09:00:00.000Z
toLocaleString 30/08/2019, 10:00:00
```

...which makes sense, 10:00:00 BST is 09:00:00 GMT.

> But doing it like this doesn't care about dst and I get an date, which is in the summer one hour ahead.

Correct. You need to provide the correct offset for the date. Your list of timezones should have DST information (if not, it's incomplete and, unfortunately, fairly useless). To do that properly you need to use the a proper timezone database such as the [IANA one](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). Your best bet for that isn't to do it yourself, but to use a library that does it for you, such as [Moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) or the one you found, [spacetime](https://github.com/spencermountain/spacetime). But yes, you could use those database files directly, they're accessible from the link above. But note that common timezone shorthand terms like "BST" (for British Summer Time) or "EDT" (for U.S. Eastern Daylight Time) are **not standardized** in any way. The IANA database uses zones like `Europe/London` *(insert Brexit joke here)*.

Comment: That does exactly the same as my code - the problem is dst, which isn't respected in the timezone offset.

Comment: @Philipp - No, it doesn't do exactly what your code does. It creates the string in the only supported format (the string you're creating does not and is not guaranteed to work cross-browser). I've updated to address the DST thing, sorry I missed that at the end of the question (not like it was a long question! shouldn't have missed it).

Comment: I know the moment timezone library, but this is a huge thing and I hoped there's something more lightweight

Comment: @Philipp - I'm sure there are others, but any good one will use the IANA database as that's the gold standard for this information. Sadly, DST and even fundamental timezones have changed repeatedly and continue to change, so a DB like the IANA one is the only way to accurately know the offset for a given date in a given location. :-| (Personally: I'd love to see some standard akin to [ECMA-402](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/) that is separate from JavaScript, but provides an API to the IANA information that you *know* nearly every environment already holds...)

Comment: I now came up with the `spacetime` library. `spacetime(``${date} ${time}``, timezone).d` returns me a `Date` object, which I later can use again for json requests.

Comment: @Philipp - [This one](https://github.com/spencermountain/spacetime)? Cool. And the more I think about this, the more I think this sort of operation belongs in ECMA-402. I may raise an issue. I mean, this comes up all the flippin' time. :-)

Comment: The IANA representative locations are OK as long as you know which one to use. ;-)

Comment: WRT Ecma, Please see (and contribute to) https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint - Yeah, I ran across that looking into whether this would fit with ECMA-402 and was much encouraged. :-)

Comment: @Philipp - FYI, the [proposal Matt mentions above](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal) would handle this via ```CivilDateTime.fromString(`${date}T${time}`).withZone("appropriate zone")``` where `"appropriate zone"` is the name of an IANA Zone or Link. The result is a `ZonedDateTime`. You'd use that instead of `Date` (but there's a way to convert to `Date` if necessary).